# How to write a script in ruby that adds the playtime of movies up

Tags: ruby

I have various folders with .avi and .mkv files in it.
I would like to write a script in ruby to count all these files and extract their playtime to see how much time I have spent watching movies.
I am new to programming, so I have no idea how to access the metadata in these files.

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not finding a Ruby gem for this very quickly. You might need to find and make use of raw command line tools for this job.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it, but there is a gem called [rvideo](http://rvideo.rubyforge.org/), which allows you to get video file metadata (it uses ffmpeg underneath).

According to the documentation to get the video file duration you'd just have to run:

```
RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => "some_file.avi").duration
```

Couple that with [Dir.glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000629), and you're pretty much set.